# "Wrong answer" in HackerRank "Day 2: Operators" challenge

Tags: c, scanf

I am a novice programmer and coder. So, I have taken 30 days of coding challenge in HackerRank, but when I am running [the "Day 2: Operators" problem](http://hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem) in C, it shows no errors. The code is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int total;
    double meal_cost; 
    scanf("%lf", &meal_cost);
    int tip_percent; 
    scanf("%i", &tip_percent);
    int tax_percent; 
    scanf("%i", &tax_percent);
    double tip = (meal_cost * tip_percent) / 100;
    double tax = (meal_cost * tax_percent) / 100;
    total = (int)(meal_cost + tip + tax);
    printf("The total meal cost is %d dollars.", total);
    printf("The total meal cost is %d dollars.", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
12.00
20
8
```

Expected output:

```
The total meal cost is 15 dollars.
```

Actual output:

```
Wrong Answer
```

Comment: I get the correct output, despite not trusting your code because it's so unreadable. Don't write long expressions with lots of casts and parentheses, and use enough whitespace, around operators the clarify a lot.

Comment: Are tips taxed? And why is the `total` an `int`?

Comment: How do you know the expected answer? Even if tips are untaxed, the total would be `12.00 * 1.28` which is `15.36`

Comment: @Bathsheba, As the problem total round-off to integer

Comment: If tips are taxed that would be `15.552` which rounds to `16`. You have truncated.

Comment: plz guys go to this linkhttps://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem

Comment: Sorry I don't have an account at hackerrank. But from what I know of such sites, they don't tell you the answer, only right, wrong, error, or time limit.

Comment: `Wrong Answer` is not the actual output. It's what the site uses to tell you that you got it wrong.

Comment: @Weather Vane, very simple make a new account

Comment: Why? It's not my problem.

Comment: just for a help

Comment: @vishalnechwani You could at least post a working link. Right now it requires manual copy/paste because you didn't add a space.

Comment: @ melpomene , HackerRank checks your answer with the number of test cases, At final case I am getting wrong.You can test this Have a link above ----> https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem

Comment: @vishalnechwani that is a challenge site. If I create an account and solve the problem, why should I tell the answer? I would submit it myself. If you can't solve a problem, move on to another one.

Comment: @vishalnechwani having looked at the question (they even give you the code!) I can see you have not rounded the answer. So the rounded-down answers were correct, but the rounded-up were not. Please read the problem statements very carefully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not read the problem statement carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This is more clear program. As it was discovered tips are NOT taxed.

Calculations are done on `double` to avoid early truncations. Final result is printed as `double` or as needed by `Hackerrank` rounded to the `int` number.

Contribution and help of `Weather Vane` is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    double total, meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent, tip, tax; 

    scanf("%lf", &meal_cost);
    scanf("%lf", &tip_percent);
    scanf("%lf", &tax_percent);        

    tip  =  (meal_cost*tip_percent/100.0);
    tax  =  (meal_cost*tax_percent)/100.0;

    // Tip taxed:
    // tax  =  (meal_cost + tip) * (tax_percent/100.0);
    // no tax on the tip:
    tax  =  meal_cost * (tax_percent/100.0);

    total=  meal_cost + tip + tax;

    printf("The total meal cost is %.2f dollars.\n",total);
    printf("The total meal cost is %d dollars.\n",  (int)(total+0.5));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
20
8
The total meal cost is 15.36 dollars.
The total meal cost is 15 dollars.
```

Comment: Casting as `(int)` does not implement the requirement: *We round  to the nearest dollar (integer) and then print our result, .*

Answer (score 0):

### Running code  "Day 2: Operators" problem in C

- Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the
   percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent
   (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal,
   find and print the meal's total cost in a HackerRank

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
double total, meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent, tip, tax;
scanf("%lf", &meal_cost);
scanf("%lf", &tip_percent);
scanf("%lf", &tax_percent);        

tip  =  (meal_cost*tip_percent/100.0);
tax  =  (meal_cost*tax_percent)/100.0;
// Tip taxed:
// tax  =  (meal_cost + tip) * (tax_percent/100.0);
// no tax on the tip:
tax  =  meal_cost * (tax_percent/100.0);
total=  meal_cost + tip + tax;
printf("%d",  (int)(total+0.5));

return 0;  }
```

### Input

`12.0
 20
 8`

### Output

`15`

Comment: Casting as `(int)` does not implement the requirement: *We round  to the nearest dollar (integer) and then print our result, .*